# A function $f$ is measurable if and only if $\arctan f$ is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

How do we prove that a function $f$ is measurable if and only if $\arctan(f)$ is measurable?

If I use the definition of measurable functions, that is, a function is measurable if and only if its inverse is measurable?

Comment: Cite the definition a bit *more precisely*, for a start..

Comment: That definition is wrong.

Comment: Why don't you mention arctan in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I will assume we are talking about real-valued functions)*

To prove the first implication, assume that $f$ is measurable.

Take $V\subset\mathbb R$ open. Write $g=\arctan$. Then $(g\circ f)^{-1}(V)=f^{-1}(g^{-1}(V))$. As $g$ is continuous, $g^{-1}(V)$ is open. As $f$ is measurable, $f^{-1}(g^{-1}(V))$ is measurable. So $g\circ f$ is measurable.

For the converse, suppose that $g\circ f$ is measurable. Then $f=\tan\circ(g\circ f)$. As $\tan$ is continuous on the image of $g$, we can apply the argument in the first part of the proof to get that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed it is a real valued function. I suppose I can proceed the same way to prove the same but with sine.

Comment: Yes, but with trig functions you always have to be careful with domains: $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ is not necessarily $x$ for an arbitrary $x$.

Comment: Can you show the converse part ? Cannot we use that f is a composition of two continuos functions therefore continuos and so f is measurable? U is open in R thus measurable under the Lebesgue measure?@Martin Argerami

Comment: Can I sat, if U is open in R so g(U) is open too as g is continuos. Then, $(g\circ f)^{-1} (g(U))= f^{-1}(U)$ is measurable (as $g\circ f$ is measurabke). Thus, f is measurable.

Comment: @user726608: it is not true in general that continuous functions are open. It is true for this particular $g$, because it has a continuous inverse; and that's exactly what I did in my answer.

Comment: If I have a function $f: R\to R$ defined as : f(x)=sin(2x) if x>0 , f(x)=1+cos(x) if x≤0. In order to show that it is measurable, I can say that both sin2x ,cosx+1 are continuos in the given intervalsbut that is not enough to conclude that f is continuos..! @Martin Argerami

Comment: Your $f$ is not continuous at $0$. Your function is of the form $g\,1_A+h\,1_B$. Sums and products of measurable are measurable.

Comment: Yes، you took $A=(0,\infty)$ and $B=(-\infty,0]$ so since they are Lebesgue measurable then $1_A, 1_B$ are measurable too ? @Martin Argerami

Comment: Yes. $\ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Since f is measurable and arctan is continuous therefore arctan f is Lebesgue measurable. If arctan f is measurable, then tan arctan f is Lebesgue measurable (because tan is continuous) therefore f is Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: thanks! But how I prove that tan and arctan are measurable?

Comment: This is *not* a correct argument. The composition of Lebesgue measurable functions is not necessarily Lebesgue measurable. What you do have is that if $(X,\Sigma_1)$, $(Y,\Sigma_2)$ and $(Z,\Sigma_3)$ are measurable spaces and $f: X\to Y$ and $g: Y\to Z$ are measurable, then $g \circ f$ is measurable. But we have to be careful when arguing about Lebesgue measurable functions because we give the domain the Lebesgue algebra and the codomain the Borel algebra.